# assigning an array as an element to linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I wanna assign a array as an element of a linked list but when I printed the list the array of i noticed all node's array has changed to the last value that user entered

first  i created a struct :

```
struct book{
char* name;
struct book *link;
};
```

then added this function to add node

```
void add_at_end(struct book *head , char* name){
struct book *temp = (struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
struct book *ptr;

ptr = head;
temp->name = name;
temp->link = NULL;

while(ptr->link != NULL){
    ptr = ptr->link;
}
ptr->link = temp;
}
```

then added this function to print the list

```
void print_list(struct book *head){
int n=1;
struct book *ptr;
ptr = head;
printf("\nTHE LIST\n");
while(ptr != NULL){
    printf("%d)book name : %s",n,ptr->name);
    ptr = ptr->link;
    n++;
}
printf("\n\n");

}
```

these are my inputes :

```
a , b
```

and this is the output :

```
1)book name : b 
2)book name : b
```

do i need to allocate a memory to name or creating another function?

I would really apreciate your help , i'm new to this,
thanks

Comment: "*do i need to allocate a memory to name*". Yes probably. It depends what `name` is that is passed to `add_at_end`. Looks like it may be the same pointer every time. In which case you need to do something like `temp->name = strdup(name);` Please provide complete code as a [mre] for a more definete answer.

Comment: Unless you copy the string into new storage, your later values overwrite the earlier ones.  If you print the pointer values, you'll see they all store the same number, and a single pointer can only point to (at most) one string.

Comment: [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) is your friend here.

Comment: @whyidbd  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313939/linked-list-of-arrays-in-c/71314336#71314336